# Programmatically rematch unmatched addresses using a different composite locator

Tags: arcpy, geocoding

I have a table of about 1500 addresses that updates and geocodes nightly using task scheduler and a couple of python scripts. The majority of these addresses are in the county for which I work. We have a local composite locator that can get all these addresses no problem, but the locator fails to match the addresses outside the county because it is built on county-wide datasets. The addresses that do occur outside the county range all over the United States.

So, instead I have it set up to connect to and use the ESRI World Geocoding service to geocode the addresses each night, which works like a charm. However, with 1500+ addresses geocoding nightly, this is very credit-intensive, and since we can geocode the majority of them without using the service, I am looking for a way to use our local locator first, and then rematch the unmatched (out of county) addresses using the ESRI World Geocoding service. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

ESRI has a 2016 post that says you can do this with VB. https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000003504

I've never done this, but straight from their site it mentions the following steps:

> 1. Procedure In ArcCatalog, create the geocoding service you want to use
>      to rematch the unmatched addresses in the geocoded shapefile or
>      feature class.
> 2. Paste the following VBA code into the VBA editor in
>      ArcCatalog. This code assumes you already have a reference to the
>      geocoded shapefile or feature class and to the geocoding service (in
>      this case, a ZIP (5-Digit) geocoding service) you want to use to
>      rematch the unmatched addresses. This code also assumes the geocoded
>      shapefile or feature class has a field that contains the 5-digit ZIP
>      code of the addresses (in this case, a field named "ARC_Zone").
>
> Code:

```
Sub AttachNewLocator(pFeatureClass As IFeatureClass, _
    pLocator As ILocator)
  Const FIELD_ZIP_NAME = "ARC_Zone"
  Dim pLocatorAttach As ILocatorAttach
  Dim pLocatorDataset As ILocatorDataset
  Dim strMatchFields As String

  Set pLocatorDataset = pLocator
  Set pLocatorAttach = pLocatorDataset.LocatorWorkspace
  strMatchFields = MatchFields(pLocator)
  pLocatorAttach.AttachLocator pLocator, pFeatureClass, _
    pFeatureClass, FIELD_ZIP_NAME, pFeatureClass.OIDFieldName, _
    pFeatureClass, strMatchFields, pFeatureClass.OIDFieldName
End Sub

Function MatchFields(pAddressGeocoding As IAddressGeocoding) As String
  Dim i As Long
  Dim pMatchFields As IFields
  Dim strMatchFields() As String

  Set pMatchFields = pAddressGeocoding.MatchFields
  ReDim strMatchFields(pMatchFields.FieldCount - 1)
  For i = 0 To pMatchFields.FieldCount - 1
    strMatchFields(i) = pMatchFields.Field(i).Name
  Next i
  MatchFields = Join(strMatchFields, ",")
End Function
```

> 3. Write a procedure in VBA to obtain a reference to the geocoded
>      shapefile or feature class and the geocoding service, and to call the
>      AttachNewLocator procedure. There are numerous examples of how to
>      obtain a reference to a shapefile or feature class in the ArcObjects
>      Developer Help.
> 4. Run your procedure to attach the new geocoding service
>      to the geocoded shapefile or feature class.
> 5. In ArcCatalog, rematch the
>      unmatched addresses in the geocoded shapefile or feature class.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in python. I would suggest that you use a Boolean, and to start off set it to false.

Example:

candidateFound = False

Then with candidateFound == False, make a call to your local geocoder, if candidate is found then set candidateFound = True. 
Else if candidateFound = False then make you call to the ESRI world geocoder.

With the Boolean you are controlling what address is sent to using your credits.